# How to convert NSObject to NSDictionary or how to access NSObject key Swift3

Tags: swift3

I`m new on this I hope you can help me.

I recibe a variable in a function, this variable is a key value object and I have the next code to set this var.

```
let params = command.arguments[0] as? NSObject
```

If I print this variable the result is:

```
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x17024fea0>(
{
    coordinate = "xxxxxxx,xxxxx";
    identifier = cordstrab;
    latitude = "xxxxxxxx";
    longitude = "xxxxxxx";
    note = Trabajo;
    radius = 5;
    type = onEntry;
}
)
)
```

I want to be able to acces to the data, I'm trying with

```
let lat = (params?.value(forKey: "latitude") as! String)
```

I don´t know what is wrong or how can I get the the values of this object.

Comment: It is an array of dictionaries. you need to do params?[0].value(forKey...)

Comment: If I add [0] throws NSObject has no subscript members

Comment: its because you have casted it as NSObject. chnage it to command.arguments[0] as? NSArray

Comment: Thanks a lot @TejaNandamuri you can put your comment like an answere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the object seems to be an <strike>dictionary</strike> array cast it to an <strike>dictionary</strike> array and use key subscription for the dictionary

```
if let params = command.arguments[0] as? [[String:Any]], let dict = params.first {
   let lat = dict["latitude"] as! String // the output is clearly string
   let long = dict["longitude"] as! String
   ...
}
```

Don't cast objects to `NSObject` in Swift unless the compiler tells you.

Comment: how can I cast to a dictionary ? :(

Comment: My code **does** cast the object to Swift dictionary (`[String:Any]`). Don't use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift, you throw away the strong type information.

Comment: Well I put your code and I debug it, but it jumps the if statement

Comment: If the output is exactly `params` then the object is an array. I edited the answer.

Comment: What I do is  cast as NSArray and for access I do let lat = ((params?[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "latitude") as! NSNumber) I don`t know if this is te best practice but is te solution for now.

Comment: `AnyObject` is bad, `NSArray` is bad, `valueForKey` is bad. My edited code is supposed to work in a Swift way.

Comment: So, for each key I have to do the same?, or I can put all may variables inside that code block

Comment: And why is bad the other way I exposed ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and the short explanation I`m new on this.

Comment: `valueForKey` is a KVC method, you should use it only if you can explain why you explicitly need KVC, `NSArray` lacks type information and `AnyObject` is too unspecified for this kind of data.

Comment: Well I have another question, how can I parse to string the value for the key note ? :(

Comment: Exactly the same way as lat and long: `let note = dict["note"] as! String`. Please try to understand what the code does

Comment: I understand it, and I coded exactly what you wrote but it throws an error.  :(

Comment: What error? According to the output the value for key `note` can only be `String`. You might post the JSON string rather than the collection type representation, the types are more distinct.

Comment: Well, what i'm doing uses cordova and I send the JSON via Javascript, the function retrieve the JSON in this way: @objc(addGeotification:)
    func addGeotification(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {}  I guess this affects the array structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145992/discussion-between-jorge-mejia-and-vadian).

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't help further, I don't use Cordova and have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your response says it is an array of dictionaries. you need to do

```
  params?[0].value(forKey...)
```

But before that you need to cast it as

chnage it to

```
  command.arguments[0] as? NSArray
```

As vadian suggests , try not to use NSArray. Use more like a swift array!